# How to get selected value of ComboBox in Silverlight if Value in DataTemplate using C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

> My XAML Code is

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="ComboBoxTemplateCategory" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" SelectedValuePath="Text"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=TemplateName}" Width="100"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

and

> C# Code

```
string mySelectedValue = ((TextBlock)((ComboBoxItem)
ComboBoxTemplateCategory.SelectedItem).Content).Text;
```

not working..

Answer (score 0):

string SelectedValue = ((BulkEmailNew.BulkEmailService.TemplateCategory)(ComboBoxTemplateCategory.SelectedItem)).TemplateName;